# to count the no of days present and absent

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have stored the Employee's Attendance Like the following.....

```
Columns  :  EmployeeCode Day1   Day2   Day3 ................ Day31

Values     :  EC001      P       P      A                       A
```

For my Purpose i need to get the Present Day Count & Absent Day Count for Every Employee. How Could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Hi just copy and paste this code and it will work fine. Just check if change the table name as to what you have in your database. Please don't forget to vote if this helps. Thank you!

```
declare @tableName varchar(100)
declare @tableFieldId varchar(100)

set @tableName = 'tbl_Attendance'
set @tableFieldId = 'EmployeeCode'




------------- no need to edit from here -----------------------

declare @sql nvarchar(Max)
declare @Present nvarchar(Max)
declare @Absent nvarchar(Max)


Set @sql = 'Select ' + @tableFieldId + ''
set @Present = ''
set @Absent = ''
select 
    @Present = @Present + ' case when ' + syscolumns.[name] + ' = ''P'' then 1 else 0 end + ' + char(10) + char(13),
    @Absent = @Absent + ' case when ' + syscolumns.[name] + ' = ''A'' then 1 else 0 end + ' + char(10) + char(13)
from sysobjects inner join syscolumns on sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
where sysobjects.[name] = @tableName 

-- remove last +
set @Present = lefT( @Present, len(@Present) - 4) + char(10) + char(13)
set @Absent= lefT( @Absent, len(@Absent) - 4) + char(10) + char(13)

set @sql = @sql + ', Present =' +  @Present + ', Absent =' +  @Absent + 
'from ' + @tableName +  char(10) + char(13) 


exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: @user518363: please vote or mark as answered to make it complete.